# 「がる」と「と思っている」の違いがありますか

Tags: grammar, word-choice, verbs

「がる」と「と思っている」の違いは何ですか

例えば、

> その地方の人々はこの宝物が珍しがっている
>
> その地方の人々はこの宝物が珍しいと思っている

Comment: 「この宝物**が**珍しがっている」じゃなくて「この宝物**を**珍しがっている」 ですね。。

Answer (score 2):

I will keep it simple to make it easy to understand. I am sure someone else can provide a more detailed answer.

「XXXがっている」 is used to express that someone currently seems or appears to be XXX, or feels XXX.

- 怖がっている　＞＞＞ Appears to be scared
- 嫌がっている　＞＞＞ Seems to hate something
- 欲しがっている ＞＞＞ Appears to want something
- 珍しがっている　＞＞＞ Appears to find something curious

「思っている」 means that someone thinks a certain way.

An easy way to distinguish the two is that 「がっている」 is more about observation of one's state of emotion, whereas 「思っている」 presumes how one is thinking. However, this is not an exact distinction and there will be cases where this does not necessarily apply.

Comment: Excuse Me, Can I use がっている in myself? For example: **私**は帰りた**がっている**? Thank you.

Comment: @HING no you can't use がる about yourself. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between がる and 思う is that がる is used when **describing how other people** think/feel (or appear to think/feel).

がる cannot be used about the speaker. The point is that you can never know exactly what someone else is actually thinking or feeling, even if it may seem obvious. So in general, 思う is avoided when the speaker is talking about how others think/feel. Instead, がる is used to indicate what the speaker believes they are thinking/feeling, based on appearances.

From the speaker's point of view,

僕は新しい車が欲しいです
is correct, but

トムは新しい車が欲しいです
is **not** correct because the speaker can't be 100% positive that Tom actually wants a new car. Therefore, the speaker uses がる to indicate what appears to be case, i.e. that Tom seems to want a new car. And accordingly...

トムは新しい車を欲しがっています
is the correct way to state this from the speaker's point of view.

Comment: What about if you're 100% sure Tom wants a new car (let's pretend he told you so the day before)?

Comment: @Ushiromiya maybe he’s lying :). The point is that in Japanese the convention is to use がる when describing other people’s feelings from your point of view. You can report what he said directly - トムは新しい車が欲しいと言っていました。is fine because it’s no longer your assumption, but rather a direct report of what he said.